# no input specified error on godaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I using url rewrite for converting dynamic to static url .

My static url

```
http://ncrjobs.in/jobs-details.php/id/10898/job_company_name/LPIT%20Software%20Solutions%20Pvt%20Ltd%20OPC
```

The dynamic url

```
http://ncrjobs.in/jobs-details.php?id=10898&job_company_name=LPIT Software Solutions Pvt Ltd OPC
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*?).php/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?) $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5 [L,QSA]
```

PHP5.ini

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

The error I'm getting is "no input specified"

```
Request URL:http://ncrjobs.in/jobs-details.php/id/10898/job_company_name/LPIT%20Software%20Solutions%20Pvt%20Ltd%20OPC
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Comment: Guys removed h from http in 2 links

Comment: Did you remove the "h" on purpose? If not, you can [edit] your post to fix it. The formatting could use some improvement as well.

Comment: Are you using "codeigniter"?

Comment: @vesan I have removed h as system allowed me to post only one link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1897200/gunaseelan I am using core php on godaddy's shared server